# Best way to switch views inside widget?

Tags: website-design, web-app, material-design

I am building a web application, and I am currently using Floating Action Buttons in the bottom right hand corner of certain predefined widgets to toggle between a main view and a settings view as indicated by their respective icon.

I have two dilemmas that I am now facing --

1. I want to add a main floating action button in the bottom right of the application to trigger the adding of dynamic widgets, and I fear that this would result in floating action button overkill if these exist on widgets too.
2. I could use a tab view inside the widget to switch between main and settings views, except that I am using this in the settings view inside each widget ([example](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.tabs))

What would be the best way to switch views inside a widget without using a floating action button?  Or on the contrary, what would be the best way to add a dynamic widget (preferably in accordance to material design specs) that is not a Floating Action Button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to place a view switcher in the top bar (eg a settings cog icon).

Floating Action Buttons (FABs) are not commonly used to switch views. FABs should represent the essential and primary action or purpose of a page, and that is rarely "switch views".

You may want to refer to the resources in this question for more reading on how to use a FAB correctly:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/81457/62445

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your reply.  I like the idea of the cog icon being used in the title bar.  That is also a great resource for using FABs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I really like toggle switches for this. They are easy to understand, indicate the current view, and are visually differentiated from buttons, tabs, and other kinds of nav.

[image]

One challenge is that Material guidelines suggest toggles be used to indicate "On" and "Off" for a particular setting. Sometimes, switching views conforms to this, as in my example, where the two views amount to adding/removing extra detail. In other cases, like the one you describe, a toggle would not be appropriate if you are adhering strictly to Material.

In these cases, and in cases where there are more than 2 views, I use tabs that are visually distinct from my navigation. While the nav might be the kind of text+underline motif that Material uses, my toggle might look like a more traditional tab:

[image]